# How to loop keyboard button on my telegram bot in python

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm new in python and telegram bot. I would like to loop the data from MySQL database and print it as buttons. "Restaurant","Hotel","Flight" are getting from MySQL database. Now, I would like to print these three data as KeyboardButtons to replace "Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3". Is it possible to get data from MySQL database and loop it as KeyboardButtons ? Thanks in advance!

```html
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='',
    database='my_telegram_bot')

sql = mydb.cursor()

def startCommand(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):

    sql.execute("select name from types")
    sql_result = sql.fetchall() 

    for x in sql_result:
      context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=x)
      
    buttons = [[KeyboardButton(button1)], [KeyboardButton(button2)], [KeyboardButton(button3)]]
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="What kind of places are you looking for?", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(buttons))
```

[image]

My result

My expected result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the markup.add() function:

```
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()

for x in sql_result:
  markup.add(types.ReplyKeyboardButton(x[0]))

context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="What kind of places are you looking for?", reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: sql = mydb.cursor()

def startCommand(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):

    sql.execute("select name from types")
    sql_result = sql.fetchall() 

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()

    for x in sql_result:
      markup.add(types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(x))

    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="What kind of places are you looking for?", reply_markup=markup)

Comment: No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\dispatcher.py", line 555, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Admin\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\handler.py", line 198, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\telegram_bot_python.py", line 179, in startCommand
    markup.add(types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(x))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\telebot\types.py", line 966, in add
    button_array.append(button.to_dict())
AttributeError: 'ReplyKeyboardMarkup' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

Comment: I added the code but getting the error when the bot is running. It's show "AttributeError: 'ReplyKeyboardMarkup' object has no attribute 'to_dict'". May I know how can I fix it?

Comment: What type of data structure is sql_result? Looking at it again, it seems to be a nested list. You can try:
        for x in sql_result:
      context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=x[0])

Comment: Alternatively, you can flatten the nested list and use the same loop.

Comment: No worries! Would love it if you could accept my answer as the best one.